# How to apply function to each group of data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called covars with three ethnicities. How do I apply function `Get_STATs` so I can get the output for each ethnicity?

Right, now I am running it like this:

```
tt <- covars[covars$ETHNICITY == "HISPANIC",]
Get_STATs(tt)

tt <- covars[covars$ETHNICITY == "WHITE",]
Get_STATs(tt)

tt <- covars[covars$ETHNICITY == "ASIAN",]
Get_STATs(tt)
```

I tried to run it like this
`aggregate(covars, by = list(covars$ETHNICITY), FUN = Get_STATs)`
which generates error `rror: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Please do specify the package having the function `Get_STATs`

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate` runs on each column separately, we may need `by`

```
do.call(rbind, by(covars, covars$ETHNICITY, FUN = Get_STATs))
```

Or `split` into a `list` and loop over the `list` and apply the function

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(covars, covars$ETHNICITY), Get_STATs))
```

If we need the ETHNICITY names as well

```
lst1 <- split(covars, covars$ETHNICITY)
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, ETHNICITY = names(lst1), lapply(lst1, Get_STATs)))
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get this in 3 rows dataframe?

Comment: @New_to_R You can `rbind` with `do.call`, updated.  As I said in the post, it is not tested as I don't know the function or the data is not provided

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't show the ethnicity name.  How do I add that?

Comment: The labeling of ethnicity did not work. Gives multiple rows of dataframes and not just 3 rows.

Comment: @New_to_R sorry, there was a bug.  I forgot to apply the `Get_STATs` in the last code.  updated

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Get_STATs function, you can use dplyr:

```
tt <- 
  covars %>% 
  group_by(ETHNICITY) %>% 
  Get_STATs()
```